# Dual quaternion skinning with multiple weights

Tags: math, 3d, quaternions

I'm importing animated meshes from a cg software which uses 3 weights per vertex for skinning. Each one weights other rotation axis (X, Y and Z). It creates very convincing effect and I want to achieve this in my app in real-time on GPU.

At the moment I use dual quaternions for animations and I would like to weight them with those three weights instead of just one. At the beginning it looks simple - just weight i, j and k (or x, y, z in shader notations) components with those three weights:

```
q.x *= weight.x
q.y *= weight.y
q.z *= weight.z
```

but the problem lies in the real component (w). I have no idea how to properly weight it.

I've tried multiplying it by average of all three weights, but it have given me strange results:

```
q.w *= (weight.x + weight.y + weight.z) / 3
```

Average weighted by rotations around axes, works perfectly, but only with rotations around one axis. When there is non-zero rotation around 2 or 3 axes at the same time, it visually gives completely wrong results.

```
q.w *= (weight.x * q.x + weight.y * q.y + weight.z * q.z) / (q.x + q.y + q.z)
```